# Java WS Security Crypto class not initializing

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cryptography, ws-security

I am trying to create a small program in Java to create the soap security headers for an API we are working with. Everything seems to be working so far, except the `Crypto` class. If I create an object from that class, all of those methods are there but it throws a null exception whenever I try to call any of the methods.

`Crypto` is an interface that works with `CryptoBase`. I was wondering if someone might be able to tell me how to initialize this class so I can call methods on it. I have little experience working with interfaces, it seems easy but I do not think it works just by doing `Crypto cr;` and then call methods like `cr.getPrivateKey(name,pass);` which is what I am trying to do.

Please see reference below for source files of the crypto package: [LINK](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.ws/com.springsource.org.apache.ws.security/1.5.8/org/apache/ws/security/components/crypto/Crypto.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CryptoBase`](https://ws.apache.org/wss4j/apidocs/org/apache/wss4j/common/crypto/CryptoBase.html) is an abstract class that offers no methods for producing a concrete instance. So you'll need to create an instance of a non-abstract subclass.

Looking at the API docs, it seems you can choose [`CertificateStore`](https://ws.apache.org/wss4j/apidocs/org/apache/wss4j/common/crypto/CertificateStore.html) or [`Merlin`](https://ws.apache.org/wss4j/apidocs/org/apache/wss4j/common/crypto/Merlin.html). Your code would then look something like:

```
Crypto crypto = new Merlin(... constructor args here ...);
```

Note that if you define your variable as `Crypto` rather than `Merlin`, then you can only use the methods defined in the `Crypto` interface. Whether that's a problem for you depends upon your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This did initialize the class and now I can call the methods.